# Авторизация на поддомене

Tags: php, javascript, авторизация

Видел как некоторые сайты используют поддоменную авторизацию. То есть, например, на поддомене `login.example.com` вешают куки, а уже на    `example.ru/*` проверяют... не понятно, при каждом действии нужно переадресовывать на `login.example.com` и проверять?? Если нет, то как это происходит? И почему разработчики прибегают к поддоменной авторизации?

Comment: Авторизация на поддомене - это пускать пыль в глаза, толку ноль по сравнению с простой аторизацией.

Comment: Предполагаю, что бы разделить нагрузку на хосты. К примеру у вас есть какой то чат, который раз в 10-ть секунд проверяет там что то, туже авторизацию.
И вот не задача, что что то пошло не так при каком либо обновление, не учли что то, бывает. И вот что бы не положить основной ресурс, я бы так сделал тоже...

Comment: при каждом действии нужно переадресовывать на `login.example.com` и проверять??

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что стандарт мета-данных кукисов позволяет выставить разрешение на домен 2-го уровня и его поддомены, причём на все сразу `.site.com` (эквивалент `*.site.com`), а не на конкретный, т.е. нет возможности через запятую или как-то иначе указать список всех доменов на которых требуется авторизоваться. Выхода два, делать редирект на каждый, передавая идентификатор сессии, либо иметь единую точку авторизации - некий proxy-домен. Т.е. всё сводится к тому, чтобы передать идентификатор сессии на все желаемые домены/поддомены.

Алгоритм прост. К примеру:

- Заходим в первый раз на сайт `site.com` - кук нет
- Происходит почти незаметный редирект на `login.site.com` и если куки нет, то генерируем сессию и устанавливаем куку на `login.site.com`.
- Перередирект на `site.com` с идентификатором сессии в параметре URL-а (`site.com?sid=<хеш>`). Уставнавиливаем куку с данным идентификатором для `site.com`.
- Чтобы избавиться от идентификатора сессии в параметре URL-а делаем рефреш (т.е. редирект на `site.com` но уже без параметра). Данная манипуляция необходима исключительно для безопасности, чтобы, к примеру, случайно не засветить идентификатор в referer, ибо пользователь может после авторизации перейти по ссылке на какой-нибудь сторонний сайт.
- Кука установлена. Как только кука или сессия протухнет/будет удалена, вновь всё это повторится.

Далее, допустим мы зашли на `foo.site.com` - кук нет.

- Происходит редирект на `login.site.com` - кука есть.
- Перередирект на `foo.site.com` с идентификатором сессии
- ...

Таким образом, именно `login.site.com` хранит базовую куку с идентификатором сессии (вернее, хранилищем выступает кеш вашего браузера) и раздаёт её через редирект доверенным доменам/поддоменам.

Преимущество данного подхода в том, что можно создать единых хаб авторизации для доменов 2-го уровня. К примеру, google.com и youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

Так делают чтобы разгрузить основной сервер от авторизаций, особенно если авторизация сложная.
Перенос кук используйте.

php

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.example.com');
session_start();
```

.htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

Например у моего товарища авторизация проходит через супер-пупер криптосамописный хеш. и время доходит до полусекунды причем сильно грузит серв. поэтому для авторизации стоит отдельный серв, которому не страшны такие проседания.