# Междоменые куки

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, cookie

**Моя задача**

сайт **site1.ru** предоставляет скрипт комментариев (индивидуально для каждой страницы)  по линку (предположим) `http://www.site1.ru/comments.js` (внутри выполняются запросы ajax на `site1.ru/comments.php` куда посылается адрес, с которой идет запрос, чтобы взять все необходимые комментарии, которые относятся к запрашиваемой странице).

Клиент заносит к себе на сайт (на **site2.ru**)

```
<script src="http://www.site1.ru/comments.js"></script> 
<div id="comments"></div> (сюда вписываются все комменты, которые предоставил сервер).
```

**это работает**

- **Теперь проблема:**

Комментировать могут только люди, которые были авторизированы на `site1.ru`.

Так, как Я нахожусь на **site2.ru** (и запрос отправляется через ajax), **site1.ru** не видит необходимые для него куки для проверки авторизации.

Как можно решить проблему оптимально, без болезненно?

P.S.: Я гуглил и прочитал уйму сайтов, половину говорят об общении между site2->site1, а другие говорят про адаптацию OpenID (в случае, если нет простого решения, так и сделаю).

P.P.S.: sql скрипт проверки авторизации (т.е. мне нужен только один несчастный cookie):

```
SELECT count(`id`) as `count` FROM `users` WHERE hash = $_COOKIE['cookie_hash'] LIMIT 1
```

Comment: У меня один вопрос.а зачем сложности с `ajax` на сайте `№1`? Почему нельзя генерить контент сразу скриптом php?  А вообще, если с сайта 2 на сайт 1 посылается запрос через php, то можно в этом параметре и указать авторизован юзер или нет

Comment: Контент генерирует PHP скрипт на стороне сервера, ajax нужен для вызова этого самого PHP. С сайта 2 посылается максимум комментарий пользователя. Дело в самом этом PHP скрипте, который не видит ['cookie_hash'].

Comment: `$_COOKIE['cookie_hash']` Это типа переменная с сайта `№2` ? ... Вы меня не поняли с аяксом.. зачем фигачить аякс, когда можно сразу опрос послать к серверу и от него получить ответ. пример: `https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1`. Нежели дергать страницу, она дергает сервер, сервер идет на страницу, а страница отдает контент. не бредово ли?

Comment: $_COOKIE['cookie_hash'] это то, чем определяется авторизован ли Я на site#1. Лучший пример: https://vk.com/dev/Comments, а точнее это то, что я стараюсь сделать. Тут также Вы ставите js скрипт, js скрипт обращается на сервер который все сортирует а дальше все на выход.  Я прошу прощение, если не совсем правильно отвечаю на ваш вопрос, может туплю, несколько дней сижу над этой задачей.

Comment: подправил проблему - куки теряется потому, что запрос отправляется через ajax. Если я поставлю к примеру iframe, то куки видны.

Comment: @user3354039: Если у вас два разных домена 2-го уровня (ваших домена!), то необходимо создать домен/поддомен, который будет прокси/хабом. [Вот почитайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461829/10551) о механизме (а-ля единая авторизация на gmail, youtube  и иных сервисов google). Если же вы обращаетесь к своему поддомену (site.com -> ajax.site.com), то можно воспользоваться CORS + заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. Последний разрешает браузеру с помощью ajax (или иной транспорт, к примеру, websocket) отправлять на поддомен текущую куку.

Comment: @user3354039: Можете [посмотреть видео](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2136/) с конференции Yandex про CORS и подводные камни связанные с ним.

Comment: @user3354039: Что касается виджетов (комментариев, твитов, лайков и т.д.) для ВК и иных вендоров - вы сами добровольно размещаете у себя на сайте iframe с их логикой. Если ещё проще, то iframe, это кусок сайта вендора, который вы встраиваете на свои страницы.

Comment: @romeo мой сайт№1 - сервер. А сайт №2\3\4\5\6\7\....n это клиенты моего сайта (т.е. это может быть кто угодно).. Речь идет про мой (аля) виджет, с логикой как у соц сетей. Да, думаю, если нельзя будет решить проблему через ajax, то, заменю это iframe. . Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас правильно выполняется кроссдоменный AJAX запрос, значит это **JSONP**. При этой технологии у получателя запроса "site1" будет доступ ко всем кукам, так же, как и при запросе через фрейм.

Рекомендую начать тестирования с самого простого скрипта. 
И убедиться, что посетитель "site2" имеет куки на "site1".

Comment: Используется XMLHttpRequests. Т.к. подгружаю обычный js скрипт, без jquery (чтоб не заставлять клиента добавлять дополнительные скрипты).

Comment: XMLHttpRequests [не поддерживает](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain) кросс-доменные запросы.

Comment: Для кросс-доменных запросов используется [JSONP](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp). Куки будут доступны.